# Get wordpress formatted post content without including wordpress functions

Tags: php, wordpress, formatting

I'm creating a script that gets the content and meta of wordpress posts for an app, doing queries directly on the database because it's way faster than including the wp functions. However the problem is that the post content is saved into the db without formatting. I know that I can get it using

```
apply_filters('the_content', $content)
```

but as I said, I would like to avoid wp functions because they are really slow.

Is there any way to "simulate" apply_filters manually?
Is there a better(faster) way to include a wp function other than

```
require('../wp-load.php');
```

which seems to be very slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “cheap” method would be including the file `wp-includes/formatting.php` (and maybe others) and running your code through the desired filter functions, such as `wpautop()`.

However, this does not guarantee that the content is formatted like your WordPress blog – especially because it won't apply the modifications made by plugins. Also, if new WordPress versions introduce new or different filters, your code will not work with them without modifications.

---

I would indeed recommend including `wp-load.php` and working with the WP filter API.

I don't think it's overly “slow” (however you may define it), but if performance is an issue, I would recommend reconsidering your architecture.

For example, if you want a website to display contents from your WordPress database, don't pull and render the contents on each page request. Instead, use a caching solution – either one of those that already exist for WordPress, or one on the server level (e.g. Varnish), or you can even implement your own cache, by storing pre-rendered pages and delivering them (semi-)statically.

Comment: Including the whole wp-load takes like a second on every request on my script. Including only formatting.php did the trick, the page response is really faster.
Anyway it's also a good idea to implement pre-rendered pages, I'll take that into consideration.

Comment: Thanks for accepting/upvoting. Btw, if including `wp-load.php` takes *that* long, something's wrong. Maybe there are slow plugins installed on the blog. Anyway, glad I could help.

Comment: I don't mind much about that, the website has a lot of functionalities and it's getting a bit slow, but it won't be a problem because only few people will use it. The important thing is that the mobile app that retrieves data from the website is fast, as we want it to be an easy and fast tool to access those data.
To make it clearer, it's a kind of ads listings app, the website will be used only to create ads.